# Data structure for finding set containing element

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

What is a good data structure for finding which set an element belongs to, with N items grouped into M different sets? For example, if the sets are {A,B} , {C,D,E},  {F,G} how can I find a set given "D"?. The sets are hash sets, so a contains query within a set is O(1).

If I just have the sets in a list of sets,

```
[{A,B}, {C,D,E}, {F,G}]
```

I can get lookup by just asking each set in the list if it contains the item. This is simple to implement, the run time is linear (in the number of sets).

A faster approach is storing all sets in a hash table, keyed on every item in each set. That is:

```
[A -> {A, B},
 B -> {A, B},
 C -> {C, D, E},
 D -> {C, D, E},
 E -> {C, D, E}, 
 F -> {F, G}, 
 G -> {F, G}]
```

That structure lets me retrieve the correct set in O(1) time, but it feels inefficient and ugly. Is there a better data structure that allows for an O(1) lookup of the correct set? Should I make a lookup key by combining hashes like a kind of Bloom filter? Other ideas?

Comment: "Feels inefficient?" Have you tried it?

Comment: @larsmans "inefficient" in running time to set up: having to create & insert N dict items and duplicate the values, and inefficient in storage since for value type collections there would be many copies of each item in the sets in memory.

Comment: That takes linear time. You don't need to duplicate anything if you use references/pointers instead of values, which is easy enough in most languages.

Comment: Yes the only overhead is probably a duplicated pointer, but with a huge number of small sets that is significant. The set references can be comparable to the set contents size, e.g if sets are small, items are integers and pointers are 64 bits.

Comment: How many sets are we talking about? Billions of them? A million pointers take <8MB.

Comment: Not that many, for my concrete problem I can easily use the dictionary solution and get more than acceptable performance. I'm only asking out of curiosity what the most efficient/elegant/performant solution might be. Purely academic. "I have a solution that is good enough. What is the best solution?"

Comment: Well, as an academic (really :) I'd say linear time preprocessing is pretty darn optimal. You might be able to replace pointers with indices in a few places if you can guarantee you'll never have more than 2^32 (or even 2^16) elements to save a factor 2 (or 4).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement in this way:

You will need an array of trees. index will be the set number.

Have a hash table to store (element, index) pair for each element in the entire lists.

For each set, you can use tree structure, unique identifier is the root and elements of the list is connected to the root.